# Nuxt server file - Inaccessible

Tags: mongodb, server, location, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am attempting to create a Twitter Clone using Nuxt3. However, due to a location issue, I cannot complete my login page.

So the following image is my file hierarchy:

[image: Files]

The important files are `useAuth.js` which is within `components/login/`, and `login.post.js`, which is within `server/api/auth/`. Here are the above mentioned files for reference:

`useAuth.js`:

```
export default () => {
  const login = ({ email, password }) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const data = await $fetch("/api/auth/login", {
          method: 'POST',
          body: {
            email,
            password,
          },
        });

        console.log(data.accessToken);
      } catch (error) {}
    });
  };

  return {
    login,
  };
};
```

`login.post.js`:

```
import { getUserByUsername, exclude } from "../../db/Users";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { sendError } from "h3";
import { generateTokens, sendRefreshToken } from "../../../components/Login/JWT";
import { createRefreshTokens } from "../../db/refreshTokens";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event);

  const { username, Pass } = body;

  if (!username || !Pass) {
    return sendError(
      event,
      createError({ statusCode: 400, message: "Missing fields" })
    );
  }

  // Is the user existing?

  const user = await getUserByUsername(username);

  if (!user) {
    return sendError(
      event,
      createError({
        statusCode: 400,
        message: "Username or password is invalid!",
      })
    );
  }

  // verify credentials

  const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(Pass, user.Pass);

  if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
    return sendError(
      event,
      createError({
        statusCode: 400,
        message: "Username or password is invalid!",
      })
    );
  }

  // Generate Token

  const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await generateTokens(user);

  await createRefreshTokens({
    token: refreshToken,
    userID: user.id,
  });

  // Cookies
  sendRefreshToken(event, refreshToken);

  return {
    accessToken: accessToken,
    user: exclude(user, ["Pass", "repeatPass"]),
  };
});
```

The issue right now is that:

I am trying to access ~/server/api/auth/login.post.js from a file which is at ~/components/login/useAuth.js, and the guy in [Youtube](https://youtu.be/_cM4j9_LfQk) used "/api/auth/login" to access it, but I am getting the above-said error. What could I have possibly done wrong?

misc:

Console log in chrome:
[image: Chrome Debug]

The VScode does not have any output related to the error faced, it is still unphased.

Comment: please show the error log too.

Comment: Added! But The VSCode does not face any error itself. the website is not broken, but the call is not made to `/api/auth/login`

Comment: well, your request showing `400`, your credential didn't match. try to create a new one